# Unable to produce the same result in python porting from matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fft

I am stuck again with this issue of not able to produce the same result in Python using numpy compared to Matlab output. I am hoping that the ported code is exactly the same in terms of what it does in Python.

Here it is-
Matlab

```
product =fftshift(fft2(alphabet)) .* fftshift(fft2(gaussmap));
combine= abs(fftshift(ifft2(product)));
```

Python

```
product =np.multiply(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(alphabet)), np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(gaussmap)))
combine= abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(product)))
```

Here are the results comparing both plotting combine
[image]

Both [alphabet and gaussmap](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtEnXvOorHZ4sqB64hEGPfLyyOLZZw?e=0cm9Ra) are 200x200 matrices. Any insights where I might be doing simple mistake here?

Comment: Guess what?  You get to show some results, preferably from a small example!  There may be someone who has wrestled with the differences in the `fft` code, but for a generic MATALB/numpy users this is specialized corner.

Comment: That MATLAB code makes me nervous... What's the casting to `double` for? Why `fftshift` each of the two results of `fft2`, and also the result of `ifft2`? That is definitely wrong.

Comment: Just updated the question with the results I am seeing and also the datasets linked as text files as they are too big to copy here.

Comment: The two pieces of code seem to do the same thing, unless the casing to `double` is meaningful. Have you compared `alphabet` and `gaussmap` in the two pieces of code? And how do you display the output?

Comment: I just removed the double and ran it again and it produces the same result. As for comparing alphabet and gaussmap, I just compared randomly and they seem to agree on both platforms making me think that they are identical

Comment: How about plotting also `product alphabet` and `gaussmap`? Maybe one of them differs between MATLAB abd Python?